# How do I debug the error java.lang.NullPointerException when the program is getting compiled and also executed halfway and then the error shows?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My program is getting compiled and executed without any errors and halfway through my program the error is being shown. I checked the code and it seemed to have a problem with the following part of the code:

```
student s[]=new student[10];
report(student s1[])
{
    this.s=s1;
}
String highmath()
{
    int temp=s[0].math;
    String name=s[0].sname;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
        if(s[i].math>temp)
        {
            temp=s[i].math;
            name=s[i].sname;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Error exception in thread main java.lang.NullPointerException at report.highmath(stdapp.java.40)

Comment: I thing debugging a little piece of code is much more efficient than writing here.

Comment: Which line is `stdapp.java:40` in your post?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You go to line 40 `report.highmath(stdapp.java.40)` and you think
what reference can be `null` on this line. It means you have a `null`
reference on that line and you're either calling a method on it, or
are trying to get one of its variables.

You can also use `System.out.println` to print out some references,
or use a debugger in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the only line it's spitting out? There should be more, because that line states that the error is in line 40 and your code that you gave us doesn't have 40 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that s[0] or s[i] for some i is null.  In other words, has s been properly initialized, before entering the highmath() method?  It appears that you are trying to initialize it in the constructor:

```
report(student s1[])
{
    this.s=s1;
}
```

But are you sure that what you are sending in to the constructor was properly initialized as well?